# How to properly check conditions in ngIf using operators to check item amount in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

Having problem showing the right `in-stock (store) or (online)` message when checking stock amount in my `json`.

So the scenario is if the stocks are less than `10` its considered as `low-stock` if its greater than `10` then `in-stock` if its `0` then `out-of-stock`.

My problem is when the stock is less than `10` my `*ngIf` sees value `0` as well so it shows `low-stock` as well as `out-of-stock`, or if stock `10` it shows `low-stock` and `in-stock`. But if the stock is greater than `10` its fine.

How can I properly check the stocks to show the right stock message?

Sample json --

```
this.checkStock = {
  "online": 0,
  "store": 10
}
```

Template with `ngIf` checks--

```
<p>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.online >= 10 "><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-2x text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i> In-stock (Online)</span>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.online <= 10 "><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x text-warning" aria-hidden="true"></i> Low stock (Online)</span>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.online == 0"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> Out-of-stock (Online)</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.store >= 10 "><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-2x text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i> In-stock (store)</span>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.store <= 10 "><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x text-warning" aria-hidden="true"></i> Low stock (store)</span>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.store == 0"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> Out-of-stock (store)</span>
  </p>
```

[Plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/jG8TCF9MDeJ39GZDIGrW?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Just add condition not to match 0:

```
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.online >= 10 "><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-2x text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i> In-stock (Online)</span>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.online <= 10 && checkStock.online > 0"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x text-warning" aria-hidden="true"></i> Low stock (Online)</span>
    <span *ngIf="checkStock.online == 0"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> Out-of-stock (Online)</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create booleans and use them:

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  checkStock: any;
  outOfStock: boolean = false;
  lowStock: boolean = false;
  inStock: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    this.checkStock = {
      "online": 0,
      "store": 10
    }
    this.outOfStock = this.checkStock.online == 0;
    this.lowStock = this.checkStock.online <= 10;
    this.inStock = this.checkStock.online >= 10;
  }
}
```

In template:

```
      <p>
        <span *ngIf="inStock"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-2x text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i> In-stock (Online)</span>
        <span *ngIf="lowStock"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x text-warning" aria-hidden="true"></i> Low stock (Online)</span>
        <span *ngIf="outOfStock"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> Out-of-stock (Online)</span>
      </p>
```

The reasoning why I prefer to create the booleans in my component's logic and avoid logic in my template is because maybe in the future the logic for the `ngIf` will be more complex than comparing to 10, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Add `&& checkStock.online != 0` to check if stock is less than 10 `and` not equal to 0